# How do I call a member function inside a non-member function in C++ with an object created in the main() function?

Tags: c++

So I am following a specific set of instructions to create a catalog-like program with a menu interface. I have a class called Dealer and I am requested to create the class object inside of `main()` and, in order to use the member functions inside that class, I am requested to call them via a non-member function. Here's what I'm asked to do:

```
int main() {
    Dealer obj1("Dealer Name");
    while(execute(menu()));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

where `menu()` is a non-member function that simply returns an `int` value depending on the option the user selects and `execute()` takes in that `int` and it must call upon the member functions inside `Dealer` class depending on what the user asks for. I understand that it is more practical to have `execute()` take in the object as a parameter and call its methods inside, but the instructions were very clear that the `main()` shown above is to be untouched.

Here are some additional instructions about `menu` and `execute`:
The `menu` method returns an `integer` value which should be used by the `execute` method to implement the selected option. The `execute` method receives an `integer` as parameter and performs the requested action by calling upon methods of the Dealer object. If the value of the parameter is incorrect the `execute` method prints an error message.

The question is how can I call the `Dealer` member functions inside `execute()` once the object is created outside that function and without using the object as a parameter for the non-member function?

Comment: So at least `execute()` needs to receive the `Dealer` object as reference parameter, or you need to make it a global variable instead.

Comment: The 'main()' function you see above is what is specifically being asked for, I can't change that.

Comment: Why you cannot change `main`? that's nonsensical requirement. What's the point of `obj1` being in main if it's not used there?

Comment: I agree, but that was the only specific requirement of the whole task

Comment: There's no way to make these functions aware about your `Dealer` object instance in the `main()` functions scope, unless doing dirty tricks using `static` functions defined by the `Dealer` class.

Comment: The constructor of `Dealer` could set a global `Dealer*` to point to `this`.  Very janky.

Comment: I added some specific info about `main` and `execute` so you can have a clearer idea what does non member functions do

Comment: @kirito23 _"The question is how can I call the Dealer member functions inside execute() once the object is created outside that function and without using the object as a parameter for the non-member function?"_ The simple answer is, you can't, unless providing something staticallyaccessiblein your`Dealer` class, and that would be considered  being a horribly bad design,  and I have serious doubts, why they wantyou to lean such. Maybe ask your instructor/tutor/teacher, if you misunderstood something.

Comment: Trust me, I'm as confused by it as anyone else, I may be a student but I think logically and this didn't make sense, which is what brought me here as a last resort

Comment: @kirito23 _@cygnus_ has shown one way, there are others as well.

Comment: @kirito23 _"but I think logically and this didn't make sense,"_ well, in courses they sometimes apply weird riddles, based on the least course learning lessons. Was there anything mentioned about `static` class members? Try to recall.

Comment: There is only one `static` attribute, but it is not even in `Dealer`, it is in another class called `Car` where we use composition to make it a private attribute for `Dealer`, but I believe it is irrelevant since that `static` attribute only keeps count

Answer (score 1):

With the outlandish requirements you specify you can accomplish it like this:

```
Dealer* lastDealer;

class Dealer {
    Dealer(const char* name) {
        lastDealer = this;
        .....
    }
    bool execute(int option) {
        .....
    }
}

bool execute(int option) {
    return lastDealer->execute(option);
}
```

I must stress, that silently setting up some global variables inside constructors or other member functions is an antipattern. I would never ask someone to do something like this, even if teaching C++. It teaches what shouldn't be done in C++, even if possible.

Comment: As I mentioned _dirty_ tricks with global variables. Could at least be nicely hidden into a private class static variable, or _Singleton_.

Comment: @CygnusX1   Thanks for your input, I'll take it into account if I have nothing left

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No matter if global, hidden static, or something else. It's the behavior that is dangerous and should not be taught: a member function changing the state of something else but the object it works on (or any of its explicit arguments if really needed)

Comment: @CygnusX1 totally d'accord 